# jQuery $.get does not work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Solution doesn't work**

Well after wasting an entire day learning front end web development, I have places the progress bar into an iframe which is launched inside the jquery dialog, expecting the ajax get requests to begin working from that page.  Unfortunately I receive exactly the same behaviour.

**Problem found**

When you press continue, a form is submitted.  As soon as this is done and a request is sent to the server, it prevents all other ajax calls from working.  Seems like a bug in webkit with no currently suggested solution:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23933

I have the following code:

```
 $(document).everyTime("3s", function() {
      $.get('uploadProgressServlet.jsp', {queue : 'parse'}, function(data){           
            <!-- Do something -->
      }
 });
```

This works fine in ie and firefox, but when I debug in chrome I hit the $.get method but never the inner function, and then when I look at the get tab I can't see any httprequest being sent to the server.  You should know I am not a front end web developer so may be missing something very obvious.

**Edit**

So here is all my code.  It looks like everything behaves as it should, but once I undo commenting of $('continue').click ... I just see the the dialog appear without anything requests being sent to the server and no errors in the console.

```
var lock = false;
var processing = false;
//$('#continue').click(function(){

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal : true,
        closeOnEscape : false,
        open: function() {

            $('#queueDiv').hide();
            $('#progressDiv').hide();
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

            //Poll place in the queue every seconds
            $(document).everyTime("1s", function() {
                if(!lock) {
                    lock = true;
                    if(!processing) {
                        $.get('uploadProgressServlet.jsp', {queue : 'parse'}, function(data){
                            $('#queueDiv').show();
                            $('#queuePlace').replaceWith(data);
                            if(data <= 0) {
                                processing = true;
                                $('#queueDiv').hide();
                                $('#progressDiv').show();
                                $('#progressBar').progressbar({
                                    value: 0
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $.get('uploadProgressServlet.jsp', {process : 'parse'}, function(data){
                            $('#progressBar').progressbar({
                                value: parseInt(data == -1 ? 0 : data)
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    lock = false;
                }
            });
        }});
    });
```

// });

So without the click method being active, a request is sent to the server and a response is received saying whether a process is in a queue or not.  When it is determined to not be in the queue an animation of a progress bar appears which polls the progress at the back end incrementing itself depending on what percentage complete it is.

When click is active, on it's invocation a dialogue appears with no content, and debugging the back end shows that new request is received any more.  There are no errors in the console.

**Edit**

Turns out this is a problem with webkit rather than chrome in particular.

Comment: have you tried running the function code ($.get...) directly?, maybe there is something surrounding it that is tripping up Chrome. Plus, are you getting any javascript errors in Chrome's console? (Press F12 and click the Console tab - see if there are any errors)

Comment: Hi, I have looked and there are no errors in the console.  I will investigate the surrounding code.

Comment: what the Jquery version you have ! I faced a problem like that with jquery 1.5 and after I updated it to 1.7 everything working now !

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. You've found the bug you seem to be running up against. Are you looking for a workaround, confirmation that the bug is definitely why your stuff isn't working or something else?

Comment: I am looking as to why $get requests don't get called in chrome on a page once I have posted a form, and why they still don't work even if I move them to be called from within an iframe.

Comment: Chrome have some security issue to get data from file in local machine or in other server. I am not sure but you may facing problem because you are trying to access file or data in your local machine or in other server.