# $.get not working in chrome but works fine in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a simple ajax `get request` to a page but it is not triggering in chrome though it works fine in firefox but when I check `$.get` in chrome developer tools it is recognised.

```
function callMainOnUnload() {
  ajaxOnunload( 'myProject/index'); 
  );
}

function ajaxOnunload(url) {
    var trackingStr = "&pageName=page1";
    $.get(url + trackingStr, function(data) {})
}
```

Solutions that I've tried:

1. Moved my project to a server and access it from my local machine's browser.
2. run chrome using the following command line: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

This is somewhat similar to [jQuery $.get does not work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314658/jquery-get-does-not-work-in-chrome) but there's no solution provided there.

EDIT:

I've tried also directly running this in chrome console.

```
$.get('myProject/index' + '&pageName=page1', function(data) {})
```

And chrome recognise it and was able to successfully fire the request.

Looks like chrome is cancelling the request for some reason

```
    1348: URL_REQUEST
http://10.32.1.10:8082/myProj/index?ajax=1&r=0.483360469681553&pageName=PERSONAL_DTLS&emailAddress=&firstName=&lastName=
Start Time: 2018-02-28 17:08:01.367

t=6488 [st=0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=1]
               --> priority = "MEDIUM"
               --> url = "http://10.32.1.10:8082/myProj/index?ajax=1&r=0.483360469681553&&emailAddress=&firstName=&lastName="
t=6488 [st=0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=6488 [st=0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=1]
                 --> load_flags = 33024 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                 --> method = "GET"
                 --> url = "http://10.32.1.10:8082/myProj/index?ajax=1&r=0.483360469681553&&emailAddress=&firstName=&lastName="
t=6488 [st=0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=6488 [st=0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=6488 [st=0]     +HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=1]
t=6488 [st=0]        CANCELLED
t=6489 [st=1]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                 --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=6489 [st=1]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=6489 [st=1] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: You get any console errors?

Comment: Are you loading the page from a server? Chrome doesn't like AJAX from local files.

Comment: No console errors. And yes, I've tried to deploy my application in a tomcat server and access it via http://{server ip}:8090/myProject but same issue is happening